# How to calculate minimal distance in arrays?

Tags: c, arrays

I have problems calculating the minimal distance in arrays. Since I'm a newbie in using C, there could be a major obvious mistake I'm making but can't spot.
I will give an example. Delta_dis should be the calculated distance.

```
array[0][0]=9.317;
array[0][1]=3;
array[1][0]=3;
array[1][1]=3;
array[2][0]=10;
array[2][1]=10;
array[3][0]=3;
array[3][1]=10;
for (i=0; i<4; i++) 
{
    for (k=0; k<4; k++) 
    {               
        delta_dis[k] = sqrt(pow((array[i][0]-array[k][0]),2) + pow((array[i][1]-array[k][1]),2));
        printf("\ndelta_dis_before[%i]: %f",i,delta_dis[k])

        if (delta_dis[k-1]!=0)
        {
            if (delta_dis[k]>delta_dis[k-1])
            {   
                delta_dis[k] = delta_dis[k-1];
            }else if (delta_dis[k]<delta_dis[k-1] & i==k)
            {
                delta_dis[k] = delta_dis[k-1];
            }else
            {
                delta_dis[k] = delta_dis[k];
            }
        }else
        {
            delta_dis[k]=delta_dis[k];
        }
        printf("\ndelta_dis_after[%i]: %f",i,delta_dis[k])
    }   
}
```

So in the first step I calculate the distance between these points. And the result (called delta_dis_before[k]) is correct. Then I want to check, if the previous calculated distance is smaller, if so, then delta_dis[k] should be exchanged with the smaller distance. However the minimal distance should not be changed if the selected arrays are the same i=k.
But as soon as I run this through, delta_dis_after is always 0.
For example what I get for i=0 is (I did round the numbers in the following)

```
delta_dis_before[0]: 0
delta_dis_after[0]: 0
delta_dis_before[1]: 6.317
delta_dis_after[1]: 0
delta_dis_before[2]: 7.033
delta_dis_after[2]: 0
delta_dis_before[3]: 9.429
delta_dis_after[3]: 0
```

but what I want is:

```
delta_dis_before[0]: 0
delta_dis_after[0]: 0
delta_dis_before[1]: 6.317
delta_dis_after[1]: 6.317
delta_dis_before[2]: 7.033
delta_dis_after[2]: 6.317
delta_dis_before[3]: 9.429
delta_dis_after[3]: 6.317
```

I hope I could explain properly what the problem is and what I want it to calculate.
Can someone please help me resolve this issue? Thank you!

Comment: You should not access `delta_dis[k-1]` if `k` is `0`.

Comment: @mch but the solution is also wrong for k=1. Or does it cancel everything because when k=0 I can't access delta_dis[k-1]?

Comment: What is the point in doing `delta_dis[k] = delta_dis[k];` ?

Comment: I wanted to make sure, that it gives out the right delta_dis[k]. But I think it's not mandatory.